# Additive subgroups of finite commutative ring with unity

Tags: ring-theory

If a finite commutative ring R with unity has no zero divisors then order of any additive subgroup of R is a prime power

Comment: Please add some context to your Question.  Presenting Readers with a bare problem statement will suggest to many of us that you have posted it without stopping to digest what is being asked.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** A finite integral domain is a field.